# Modernizr does not test all css3 features listed on w3schools

Tags: html, css, w3c, modernizr

W3schools lists a table of the new [CSS3 properties and their browser support](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp).

But modernizr tests only a subset of these features. Is there a reason for this?

Where do i find a modernizr build that tests most, if not all the features listed in w3schools?

Comment: Not all features can be tested or are worth testing.

Comment: So is the modernizr test good enough to be considered a more-or-less comprehensive CSS3 test?

Comment: @rubndsouza http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @Pete Haha. Okay. Consider me educated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the standard Modernizr build. At the website you can customize the build so that it detect more features.

http://modernizr.com/download/

Comment: I already have a custom build. I was talking about the features not included even in the custom build.